# Content deployment between SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010

Tags: deployment, content-deployment

Is it possible to deploy on a regular basis content from a SharePoint 2007 server to a SharePoint 2010 server ?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution if you have the cash is to use a 3rd party tool like MetaVis.

You can do it if the data is in a simpler format by creating a custom script that uses the client object model and/or SPServices.